# How to specify values by using Yii2 migration?

Tags: yii2, migration

I'm new to `Yii2 framework`, so. I need to specify 3 `categories` by using `Yii2 migration`.

F.e: user enters a form and in that form there is a dropdown where he can select the `category` from the specified ones, which is in the database and according to that category select `items`, which is also stored in a database.

I've created all the tables with `foreign keys` by using migration, here is the `category` table:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

class m170425_115637_sale extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('sale', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'item_id' => $this->integer(11)->notNull(),
        'customer_name' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
        'customer_surname' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
        'customer_phone' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
        'customer_email' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
        'code' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
        'sign' => $this->boolean(),
        'comnent' => $this->text(),
    ]);

    // creates index for column `item_id`
    $this->createIndex(
        'idx-post-item_id',
        'sale',
        'item_id'
    );

    // add foreign key for table `user`
    $this->addForeignKey(
        'fk-post-item_id',
        'sale',
        'item_id',
        'item',
        'id',
        'CASCADE'
    );
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dropTable('sale');
}
```

And here is `item` table:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

class m170425_114148_item extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('item', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'category_id' => $this->integer(11)->notNull(),
        'name' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
        'price' => $this->double(),
    ]);

    // creates index for column `category_id`
    $this->createIndex(
        'idx-post-category_id',
        'item',
        'category_id'
    );

    // add foreign key for table `category`
    $this->addForeignKey(
        'fk-item-category_id',
        'item',
        'category_id',
        'category',
        'id',
        'CASCADE'
    );
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dropTable('item');
}
```

I hope you understand the problem, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add some table data in the migration you can use [batchInsert()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#batchInsert()-detail).

```
$this->batchInsert('category', ['name'], [['category1'], ['category2'], ['category3']]);
```

This adds 3 rows to the `category` table by inserting in each given value for `name` column.

If you want to add more columns at once do it like that:

```
$this->batchInsert('category', ['name', 'another'], [
    ['category1', 'aaa'], 
    ['category2', 'bbb'], 
    ['category3', 'ccc']
]);
```

Comment: This should be done in `function up()`? Besides that, could you tell me the `command prompt` command to renew the old database table? I can't find it in the documentation..

Comment: Yes, you can put this in `up()`. What do you mean by "renew old table"?

Comment: I mean that with the command `yii/migrate` it's always says that the table is existing. Is it possible to do that when I make an edition to my migration, it would renew the old table with the new one (with the editions made) ?

Comment: If you want to modify already existing table create migration with [methods modifying the table](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html) like `addColumn`, `alterColumn` and so on.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But one more question. I added 3 categories by using your command, but do you have an idea how to add 5 `items` in each of the category? I thought that I can `specify 5 items` in my `item migration`, but I won't know the `category_id`... :(

Comment: You can set IDs directly instead of allowing them to be added automatically.